# Quand peut-on mettre 'avec' à la fin de la phrase ?

Tags: prépositions, syntaxe

Quelques exemples :

> Les résultats ne sont pas satisfaisants pour le moment, mais il faut faire avec.

> On a perdu le match, mais il faut faire avec.

> Il avait pris un bâton et faisait des moulinets avec.

> Ça ne vous appartient pas et il ne faut jouer avec.

Par contre on ne peut pas dire :

> Un collaborateur que je travaille avec.

et on doit dire :

> Un collaborateur avec lequel je travaille.

Alors dans quelles types de tournures on peut positionner 'avec' à la fin de la phrase ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quelques remarques préliminaires :

1. Le comportement d'*avec* décrit dans la question n'est pas unique à cette préposition, mais propre à une classe assez large de prépositions qui comprend avec, sans, contre, derrière, après, sur, dans/en et sous (sous leurs formes fortes dessus, dedans et dessous), par dessus ou encore entre. On peut rapprocher ce comportement à celui de certaines préposition complexes locutions prépositionnelles qui permettent une transformation similaire (il y avait des gens autour de Saïd -> Saïd, il y avait des gens autour // elle est passé à travers de la barrière -> la barrière, elle est passée à travers). *Pour* est parfois groupé avec les prépositions de ce type, mais son emploi est plus restreint (Authier 2016).
2. La description de ce phénomène comme "en fin de phrase" est trop limitée: une préposition peut apparaître seule partout où un groupe prépositionnel peut apparaître: "tu vas pas partir avec (elle) quand même ?"; "Avec (lui dans l'équipe), on est invincibles !" Les termes couramment utilisés pour décrire ces prépositions dans la littérature sont "prépositions sans objet", "l'emploi absolu des prépositions" ou "les prépositions orphelines" (Zribi-Hertz, 1984). Je vais surtout employer ce dernier terme (ou son abbréviation PO), qui est le plus court.
3. Les traditions grammaticale classique parle d'emploi adverbial des prépositions. C'est une description qui peut convenir avec des prépositions purement locatives comme *autour*, mais une étude plus attentive de leur usage révèle immédiatement beaucoup de problèmes avec une interprétation adverbiale. Par exemple, "Un travailleur que je travaille avec" devrait être totalement acceptable si *avec* était un adverbe. La plupart des linguistes analysent plutôt les prépositions orphelines comme intégrant quelque chose de pronominal, conceptualisé différemment selon les cadres théoriques (une trace, un pronom silencieux, un pronom absorbé dans la préposition, etc) et qui servent d'argument à leur verbe. On peut voir le plus clairement la trace de ce quelque chose  pronominal dans la transformation sur ça -> là-dessus. Je vais parfois utiliser la notation [avec PRO] (PRO étant un pronom silencieux) parce qu'elle est la plus claire, mais sans particulièrement soutenir cette interprétation théorique.

---

Pour en venir à la chair de la réponse, les prépositions orphelines sont gouvernées par un certain nombre de restrictions :

Les prépositions orphelines peuvent être utilisées dans tous les cas où un pronom défini pourrait être employé comme leur objet : J'en ai parlé avec (elle) ; ils voulaient le réparer avec (ça), etc. Avec un pronom indéfini, cet usage est bloqué : "T'es revenu avec quelqu'un alors ?" et "T'es revenu avec alors ?" ont des sens différents.

Certaines prépositions ne peuvent être orphelines que dans certains dans leurs sens, mais ce n'est pas le cas de *avec*, simplifiant fortement cette réponse (Authier 2016).

Dans le cas d'*avec* en particulier, les dialectes diffèrent par la personne du pronom sous-entendu : la plupart n'admette l'*avec* orphelin qu'à la troisième personne, alors que le français de Belgique en particulier (et le français de l'Est de la France, mais de manière plus restreinte) accepte certains usages aux autres personnes : "ils sont venus avec (nous)", "tu les a pris avec (toi) ?", mais pas tous ("tu veux sortir avec (lui) ?" est acceptable pour moi, mais pas "tu veux sortir avec (moi) ?" dans son sens non-spatial)

Des expressions lexicalisées comme "faire avec" peuvent passer outre de cette restriction, cependant: "Je viens de toute façon, il n'auront qu'à faire avec". On pourrait analyser avec comme ayant un (moi/ma présence) sous-entendu, mais également comme étant une expression figée dont l'élément pronominal a disparu.

---

Finalement, qu'est-ce qui rend "Un collaborateur que je travaille avec" non grammatical ? J'ajouterai immédiatement que "Qui je travaille avec ?" présente le même problème, et que comparer les deux phrases devrait nous offrir la clé du problème : elles impliquent toutes les deux le mouvement d'un élément pronominal en tête de phrase (par rapport à leur équivalent déclaratif principal "je travaille avec (lui)"): le pronom relatif *que* et le pronom interrogatif *qui*

Or, contrairement à l'anglais (I work with them -> who do I work with ___ ?), le français n'admet pas l'extraction d'un élément pronominal hors d'un groupe prépositionnel. Si le pronom se déplace, c'est tout le groupe qui le suit :

> Je travaille avec cet homme -> cet homme, je travaille [avec PRO]

> l'homme avec qui (=PRO+relatif+animé) je travaille

> Je travaille avec qui (PRO+question+animé) ? -> avec qui (est-ce que) je travaille ?

Des phrases comme "qui je travaille avec ?" soit auraient deux éléments pronominaux (qui et "avec PRO"), soit auraient extrait l'élément pronominal hors de avec PRO, ce qui est impossible en français.

Cependant, des phrases avec une syntaxe similaire à "Un collaborateur que je travaille avec" sont bien attestées en Europe comme en Amérique, (quoiqu'elles semblent être relativement rares quand l'objet sous-entendu de la préposition est animé), par exemple "Ma gonzesse, celle que je suis avec. Ma princesse, celle que je suis son mec" dans la chanson de Renaud *Ma Gonzesse*.

De telles phrases sont plutôt stigmatisées, mais on peut les analyser comme appartenant à un autre type de relative que celles plus standards comme "Le collaborateur avec qui je travaille".

Le français a trois stratégies en compétition pour former des subordonnées relatives :

1. la personne **dont** je parle : La standard, qui utilise un pronom relatif (ici dont) qui change de forme selon son rôle dans la subordonnée, ainsi que la spécificité et le caractère animé de son référent
2. La personne **que** je parle : une des deux formes populaires, dans laquelle un pronom relatif universel *que* est utilisé quel que soit son cas ou la nature du référent
3. La personne que j'en parle / que je parle d'elle : l'autre forme populaire (moins négativement marquée à mon sens), qui utilise un marqueur relatif *que* (***qui n'est pas ici un pronom***) et un pronom de reprise dans la subordonnée qui a une forme identique à celle qu'elle aurait en tant que proposition principale.

En transposant "le collaborateur avec qui je travaille" à ces trois stratégies, on obtient :

1. Le collaborateur avec qui je travaille ("qui" étant le pronom relatif prépositionnel animé, qui a entraîné *avec* avec lui)
2. Le collaborateur que je travaille (*que* est le pronom relatif universel)
3. Le collaborateur que je travaille avec PRO (*que* est le marqueur relativiseur, avec PRO est l'élément de reprise pronominal).

Ce qui explique l'émergence occasionnelle de relatives contenants des préposition orpheline en français relaché.

---

Bibliographie:

AUTHIER J.-Marc, *French orphan prepositions revisited*, 2016

BORILLO Andrée, "Il y a prépositions et prépositions", *Travaux de linguistique*, vol. 42-43, n° 1, 2001, pp. 141-155.

GODART D. *Français standard et non-standard : les relatives*, 1989

POPLACK Shana et al., *Phrase-final prepositions in Quebec French: An empirical study of contact, code-switching and resistance to convergence*, 2012

ZRIBI-HERTZ Anne, *Prépositions orphelines et pronoms nuls*, 1984

Answer (score 4):

"faire avec", "vivre avec"... sont des expressions toutes faites.

Pour le cas "Il avait pris un bâton et faisait des moulinets avec.", on ne peut pas dire "Le bâton qu'il faisait des moulinets avec" mais "Le bâton avec lequel il faisait des moulinets". C'est à dire la même tournure que "Un collaborateur avec lequel je travaille."

Dans certaines régions proches de régions germanophones, on peut entendre des phrases telles que: "Tu viens avec?", traductions litérales de "Kommst du mit?".

Comment: "On sort en boîte, tu viens avec ?" ne me semble pas particulièrement incongru en Belgique non plus... je ne vois pas cela serait grammaticalement incorrect, tout au plus du registre familier.

Answer (score 4):

On trouve cette syntaxe particulière à « avec » (et « sans ») avec certains verbes courants et d'autres mots courants. Elle semble être beaucoup une tournure du dialogue, motivée en partie par la répétition, qui conduit à l'éllipse.

*Des exemples typiques* (Le manque de l'indication que « sans » peut être utilisé de la même façon n'est pas une affirmation que l'usage ne se trouve pas ; c'est seulement l'indication que ce n'est pas quelque chose que je sache.)

- **être** (sens de « accompagner »)     *C'est avec.* (sans)
- **être < adjectif >**                              *C'est mieux avec.* (sans)
- **faire**                                                 *Pendant longtemps il a fait avec.* (sans)
- **aller**                                        *Qu'est-ce qui va avec ?*, *Ça va avec.* (« sans » n'a pas de sens),
- **vivre**                                                *Il faut vivre avec.* (sans),
- **jouer**                                               *Elle lui a donné une babiole pour jouer avec.*,
- **venir** (sens de « être fourni »)       *Ça vient avec.* (sans)
- **venir** (déplacement)                — *Il y a un autobus qui va de la ville au village, il est venu avec.*
                                                              (« sans » n'a pas de sens.)
- **partir**                                        — *Il a rencontré une des filles de chez Jean, il est parti avec.*

C'est une syntaxe particulière à « avec »  utilisée avec d'autres verbes.

- J'ai récupéré le vieux Rolex au grenier, on trouve toujours de la pellicule et j'ai pu prendre des photos avec ; je ne sais pas ce qu'elles vaudront…

---

- **pas**           *— J'ai mis la pièce de sécurité, ça ne marche pas.*
                   — *Si, ça marche, mais pas avec cette pièce.*
                   — *Ça ne marche pas avec cette pièce ?*
                   — *Non, pas avec.* (sans)
- **et**            — *Il y avait des alcools…*
                 — *Et avec ?* (« sans » n'a pas de sens.)
- **quoi**        *— J'ai fait des frites… avec des « meat balls ».

                  — Quoi avec ?* (ou *Avec quoi ?*)

Comment: venir sans : "Tiens tu n'a pas de ceinture à ton pantalon ? Non, il vient sans." .

Comment: @LaurentS.Ça se dit aussi en  France ?

Comment: Je ne m'étais jamais posé la question avant... mais en tant que belge on ne découvre souvent les belgicismes que parce que l'on nous en fait la remarque. Cela dit "venir avec" ou "venir sans" ca me semble tout à fait habituel comme expressions.

Comment: @Pasunclue I s'agit bien d'une erreur, je la corrige.

Answer (score 2):

I posted my question [elsewhere](https://www.question-orthographe.fr/question/quand-peut-on-ecrire-avec-a-la-fin-dune-phrase/). Here is the answer that I received and that I consider to be offering much information.

> Avec en fin de phrase. Dans certains cas, c’est correct, mais familier
> (cf. le TLFi et l’Ac.) :
>
> 1. La construction  est correcte si le complément sous-entendu (nom de personne ou de chose) a été employé  précédemment (parfois sous forme
>    de proposition). On ne dira pas directement : Venez-vous avec? pour :
>    Venez-vous avec nous? Nous accompagnez-vous?«  (Joseph HANSE ,1949).
>
> Emploi adv., fam. (corresp. aux emplois prép. cités sous I et II) :
>
> 28. Enfin, un matin, le colonel cherchait sa monture, son ordonnance était partie avec, on ne savait où, dans un petit endroit sans doute
>     où les balles passaient moins facilement qu’au milieu de la route.
>     CÉLINE, Voyage au bout de la nuit, 1932, p. 16.
> 29. … et tous les quatre pas [il] s’arrêtait, soulevait son tuyau de poêle, et s’éventait avec, bien qu’il fît froid, puis sortait un
>     sordide foulard de sa poche et s’épongeait le front avec, puis le
>     rentrait; … GIDE, Les Nouvelles Nourritures, 1935, p. 262.
> 30. … vivre dans une époque, dans un milieu, où le mensonge décent est de règle, où le conformisme social et moral s’entoure d’un appareil de
>     puissance impressionnant, et qui, n’ayant pas l’héroïsme (…) de faire
>     sauter toute la boutique et lui avec, (…), se réfugie dans un discours
>     secret, … ROMAINS, Les Hommes de bonne volonté, La Douceur de la vie,
>     1939, p. 8.
>
> L’Académie française donne, elle, cet ex. : Il a pris son manteau et
> s’en est allé avec, que J. Hanse juge « familier mais certainement
> acceptable ».
>
> 2. L’Académie donne cet autre exemple qui va plus loin (ici, avec signifie « en plus ») :
>
> Il a été bien traité et il a encore eu  de l’argent avec. C’est
> également familier.